# ActiveRecord task executing in wrong environment with Whenever

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, whenever

I have to run a Cron task involving some data cleaning in my ActiveRecord database. I am using Whenever gem. Here is the code :

*schedule.rb*

```rb
every 1.hour do
  rake 'notifications:clear'
end
```

*notifications.rake*

```rb
namespace :notifications do
  task clear: :environment do
    Rpush::Notification.delete_all
  end
end
```

Running this gives me the following error:

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL:  role "user_prod" does not exist
```

I am in development environment. Here is my database.yml file :

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: development_database

test:
  <<: *default
  database: test_database

staging:
  <<: *default
  database: staging_database
  username: user_staging
  password: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>


production:
  <<: *default
  database: production_database
  username: user_prod
  password: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Any ideas on why my ActiveRecord instruction seems to connect to my production environment ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update Your code with below :-

In **schedule.rb** file :-

```
every 1.hour do
  rake 'notifications:clear', :environment => "development"
end
```

And finally executed this command :-

```
whenever --update-crontab
```

**OR**

Clear existing cron jobs.

```
crontab -r
```

Update cronjob with the environment.

```
whenever --update-crontab --set environment='development'
```